# Extract Substring values with key pattern

Tags: python

Probably a regex question (forgive my broken english).

I need to identify a sub string that starts with a certain value.

For example, take the following string:

> "Select 1 from user.table1 inner join user.table2..."

I need to extract all the words that start with "user" and end with "blank space". So, after applying this "unkown" regex to the above string, it would produce the following result:

> table1
>   table2

I tried to use the "re.findall" function, but couldn't find a way to specify the start and end patterns.

So, how can extract the substrings using a starting pattern?

Comment: `re.findall(r'\buser[^ ]* ', txt)`

Comment: `[words.split(".")[1] for words in string.split(" ") if words.startswith("user")]` try like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Positive Lookbehind :

```
import re
pattern=r'(?<=user\.)(\w+)?\s'
string_1="Select 1 from user.table1 inner join user.table2 ..."

match=re.findall(pattern,string_1)
print(match)
```

output:

```
['table1', 'table2']
```

regex information:

> `(?<=user\.)(\w+)?\s`
>
> ```
> `Positive Lookbehind` `(?<=user\.)`
> Assert that the Regex below matches
> user matches the characters user literally (case sensitive)
> \. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
> 1st Capturing Group (\w+)?
> ? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> \w+ matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
> ```

If that pattern doesn't work try this :  `(?<=user\.)\w+`

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
re.findall(r'\buser\.(..*?)\b',
           "Select 1 from user.table1 inner join user.table2...")
```

This will return:

```
['table1', 'table2']
```